# Set image size in lua

Tags: image, lua, torch

I have written the following code to display an image in lua:

```
imagefile="/path/"
img=image.load(imagefile)
image.display(img)
```

The dimensions of the image are 200x200. How can I resize the image to 100*100 or some other dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no image manipulation in default environment. Names of your tables and functions seems to match Torch though. If that's the case, use `image.scale`.

Relevant quote from docs (https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/simpletransform.md#res-imagescalesrc-width-height-mode):

> `image.scale(src, width, height, [mode])`
>
> Rescale the height and width of image src to have width width and
>   height height. Variable mode specifies type of interpolation to be
>   used. Valid values include bilinear (the default), bicubic, or simple
>   interpolation. Returns a new res Tensor.